How do I change camera resolution without zooming in in Python OpenCV
From what I've seen you can alter the resolution of a frame using the following code using OpenCV:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Adjust index if necessary
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)   
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

But when I do this it essentially crops the image, zooming in so to speak. I want the acquisition field to remain the same size and lower the resolution. Are the commands listed not how one achieves this?
I also tried to lower resolution using
cap.set(3,480)
cap.set(4,640)

but the result is the exact same unfortunately

"I also tried" -- You replaced named constants with their equivalent numeric values. Functionally those two approaches are identical. The only difference is that the second one is harder to understand due to the use of magic numbers.

This closure is definitely incorrect, if there is a duplicate that ain't one.

Anyway, the behaviour is likely due to the camera you're using. Maybe play around with some tool dedicated to working with cameras and capturing video (ffmpeg, etc.). See what resolutions are supported, and whether you can achieve what you want through such tool. Then add details into the question (concrete camera, whether that mode is supported, whether it works somewhere else). And keep in mind that the ability to read cameras is just a utility feature of OpenCV.

that's not a useful canonical. it's 14 years old, with OP asking about the ancient first version of OpenCV's Python bindings. those haven't existed for at least a decade.

So I've learned that this is just how cameras work, if you lower the resolution they necessarily decrease the acquisition field, so I need I just need to keep the camera further away and manipulate the capture offset. Thank you Cristoph and Dan, you're right, that was not a correct closure.

not necessarily. look up "binning". or resize after acquisition.
